# http request in mulesoft

Tags: http, url, mule4

I am trying to pass the below url in http request connector in mulesoft.

GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/drives?q=name%20contains%20%22QA-zz-SFJobs-Contacts%22&useDomainAdminAccess=true

Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]
Accept: application/json

But am getting error as not found, but the drive is present in google drive how

Refer below image.

[image]

How can i pass the url in mule 4 http connector

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if that is the problem but the screenshot shows the path includes query parameters. You should set the query parameters in the Query Parameters tab one by one.

Also the URL has a `useDomainAdminAccess` query parameter missing.

Probably more importantly, the path has a `{name}` value, when the example URL has `%22QA-zz-SFJobs-Contacts%22`. It looks like you are trying to use a `${name}` configuration property instead.